# Got Caught Telling My Friend Something Need Help!

Tags: cheating

Okay so I am a Computer Science student Today was our Programming Fundamentals paper basically I am very good in Programming so I finished my paper early and was so happy after leaving the exam class I was going suddenly I heard a voice It was my friend I thought he gave his paper as well but no he came out of the hall for a bathroom break there was another guy with him who was there to ensure that my friend would not cheat but he allowed me to tell him some answer very quickly so we were standing outside the washroom And i was telling him answer to one pf the questions suddenly the bathroom door opened and it was one of the lab engineer's of our college he heard us over so he took us to the invigilator ho noted our registrations and names Now I am asking you Am I guilty here? And If Yes How Can I Avoid this Because I learned my lesson and now I am scared what if My Paper got cancelled or worse.

Comment: First, don't panic. Second, talk to your instuctor. Third, don't panic.

Comment: Fourth, for the love of *insert deity here* use proper sentence structure, formatting, and punctuation.  Reading this gave me a migraine.

Comment: Your school likely has a written honesty policy, and there may also be one in your course's syllabus.  Read them.  They will explain the procedures and potential punishments for cheating.  In most cases, sharing answers with someone who you know is currently taking an exam would be a clear violation of a fairly severe nature.  Whether you "learned your lesson" is something that may or may not be taken into account.

Answer (score 3):

I do have an issue with your description of events.  You state he "allowed you" to tell him an answer.  This comes across as trying to shift blame for your actions onto your friend.

To answer your question about guilt.  You are guilty of telling someone who was still taking the exam one of the answers.  Whether or not you did so knowing the other student was still taking the test or not is not up to us to decide.

There is no way for you to avoid being guilty of telling someone taking the test an answer, as you yourself admit you did it.

As far as learning your lesson, this is not up to you to decide.  This is up to your institutions disciplinary committees.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I guilty here?

Unfortunately, the answer is probably yes.

> How Can I Avoid this Because I learned my lesson and now I am scared.

Being scared and claiming that one has learned one's lesson are such universal reactions to being caught that I wouldn't expect to get much sympathy on these grounds. Moreover, playing the "I learned my lesson" card is also an implicit admission that you did something wrong. A better strategy is to insist that you did nothing wrong (idiotic as it may sound).